# Internal drive does not appear in the Recycle Bin Properties

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2003, recycle-bin

Windows 2003 Server, 2GB internal NTFS drive. 
It's not showing on the recycle bin properties.  How do I fix this?

Comment: yes, it has a drive letter.  not slaved.  sata drive.

Comment: I fixed the issue.  Disabled "Hide Protected Operating System Files."  Deleted the RECYCLER directory on each drive.  Restarted the system.